# Setting a port in Python 2.7.2 to work with Arduino Uno

Tags: python, arduino

I am working on a laser cutter/engraver, part of the Lasersaur open source laser cutter/engraver project. I completed the hardware build not realizing that there was some software programming involved, Python in this case. I know absolutely nothing about Python and what coding experience I have was in C# building a custom CMS from scratch.

This is my setup.

Computer: Toshiba Satellite A-105

OS: Windows XP, SP3

Code: Python 2.7

Dev Board: Arduino Uno

The Arduino client talks to the Uno board fine, and all the test and uploads work. Using the getting started guide from the Arduino website I was able to set up a COM port for it to use, COM7 in this case. The problem is when I run the Python GUI and compile the code provided by Lasersaur I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\LASERSAUR\lasersaur_Grbl\stefanix-LasaurGrbl-dac1a86\flash.py", line 128, in <module>
    devices = os.listdir("/dev")
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/dev/*.*'
```

The guys at Lasersaur say I need to set the COM port in the code. I just don't know enough to do it myself or to ask the right questions. However, after a lot of reading and staring at my screen, I am fairly certain that I need to set the port here:

```
## define serial port
##
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    # (1) get the serial device from the argument list
    SERIAL_PORT = sys.argv[1]
    print "Using serial device '"+ SERIAL_PORT +"' from command line."
else:    
    if os.path.isfile(CONFIG_FILE):
        # (2) get the serial device from the config file
        fp = open(CONFIG_FILE)
        line = fp.readline().strip()
        if len(line) > 3:
            SERIAL_PORT = line
            print "Using serial device '"+ SERIAL_PORT +"' from '" + CONFIG_FILE + "'."



if not SERIAL_PORT:
    # (3) try best guess the serial device if on linux or osx
    devices = os.listdir("/dev")
    for device in devices:
        if device[:len(GUESS_PPREFIX)] == GUESS_PPREFIX:
            SERIAL_PORT = "/dev/" + device
            print "Using serial device '"+ SERIAL_PORT +"' by best guess."
            break
```

I am fairly certain this will be a forehead slapping answer when I see it. But any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: "`WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/dev/*.*'`". `/dev` is a Unix path. You're running on Windows.

Comment: What command line argument are you using to launch this script? It looks like whatever arguments (if any) you are passing to the script are not getting read and python is jumping to the lower code bloc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing any arguments when you run this script from the command line? It seems as if you aren't. 
Try this from the command line:

```
    C:\>python flash.py COM7
```

If that still doesn't work (or that's what you have been doing all along), then you're probably better off putting `#'s` in front of every line in the code you posted above, and replacing it with

```
    SERIAL_PORT = "COM7"
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! I put
    SERIAL_PORT = "COM3"
at the top of the code just below the
    import os,sys
and again below the platform code block and the error went away.

... now I have a new one. But its a file call so I think I can fix it.